# How to query all users with Apttus CPQ license?

Tags: query, appexchange, licenses, connected-apps, workbench

I have been tasked with creating reports of users with the licenses they have. I have been successful in finding Force.com users, Marketing users, Knowledge Users, Content Users, Service Cloud users, Call Center users, and Avantgo users however, I have not been successful in finding a field that references the Apttus CPQ license. I've been using Workbench to find this information. How can I find all users with the Apttus CPQ license? I've tried reviewing fields in the UserProfile, User, and UserLicense objects and still have not had any luck. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you check the UserPackageLicense object? That is how most of them work. Apttus may have its own management though.

Comment: @CyberJus Thank you so much for your response! At first I could find these objects but it was because I didn't have full System Admin Access. Once that was changed and I changed the API setting in Workbench to 31, I was able to use both the UserPackageLicense and PackageLicense object with Excel VLookup to get the information I needed. Thank you so much! Can you put this as an answer so I can give you credit for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UserPackageLicense object contains records for the junction between users and package access.